# Yammer JavaScript SDK - 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cors, yammer

I'm trying to make Yammer API request as per instruction here: https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk. When I run this example:

```
yam.getLoginStatus(
  function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      console.log("logged in");
      yam.platform.request({
        url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json",     //this is one of many REST endpoints that are available
        method: "GET",
        data: {    //use the data object literal to specify parameters, as documented in the REST API section of this developer site
          "letter": "a",
          "page": "2",
        },
        success: function (user) { //print message response information to the console
          alert("The request was successful.");
          console.dir(user);
        },
        error: function (user) {
          alert("There was an error with the request.");
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      alert("not logged in")
    }
  }
);
```

I'm doing that on localhost and I'm getting following error:

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json?letter=a&page=2&_=1401954073159. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."
```

Any idea how to solve this?

One more thing. I can't specify additional headers in this as this call is executed as 'OPTIONS' not a 'GET' request method.

Hope someone had same issue with Yammer latest API and was able to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: This is sorted, whole JavaScript Origin side on Yammer it is a bit flaky but finally I got it to work

Comment: Any hints on how you made it work? Maybe you could answer your own question

Comment: hey pcv. I've answered this in next answer: 'Actual 'error' has been caused by their bad documentation. REST endpoint is api.yammer.com/api/ not www.yammer.com/api'. thanks

Comment: hmhm, that didn't work for me. I get the error no matter if I use www.yammer.com or api.yammer.com

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to update your Yammer apps JS Origins to match the environment hostnames that you are testing in.

You can configure those origins at this link here:

https://www.yammer.com/client_applications

And clicking your application, then clicking "Basic Info".

Comment: Actual 'error' has been caused by their bad documentation. REST endpoint is api.yammer.com/api/ not www.yammer.com/api

Comment: Thanks for catching that - I've updated the docs to reflect the correct API url.

Answer (score 2):

Use the hostname as "api.yammer.com" instead of "www.yammer.com".  I believe documentation needs to be updated and I'll get that updated.

Alternatively, you can use `yam.platform.request('users.json')` instead of `yam.request('https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json')` which you don't have to tweak with the hostname.

Comment: **api**.yammer.com and **www**.yammer.com are treated by the browser as two different domains which might explain the CORS error message.

Answer (score 0):

add your application url to "Javascript Origins" in yammer application basicinfo.

Comment: I hope this is not too late, but in my app's basic info page, the setting for "Javascript Origins" doesn't exist. Am I missing anything here ?