# Call Yammer API from NODE js

Tags: node.js, yammer

I am planning to call JS file , which has call to the Yammer API.

The challenge is Yammer API needs [predefined origins configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054520/yammer-javascript-sdk-access-control-allow-origin-issue) while creating an APP. In case of call being made from website its straightforward. However i am making a call thorough JS file that will be called by NODE.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Per their documentation, Yammer currently only offers a client-side SDK for javascript.